# Прилагательное или причастие?

Tags: части-речи

Какой частью речи(прилагательным или причастием) является слово "умиротворяющую" в этом предложении?
**Я слушаю умиротворяющую музыку**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причастие от глагола умиротворять - вести к миру, успокоить.Музыка, которая успокаивает. Синоним - успокаивающую.

А вот умиротворённая (улыбка) -прилагательное со знач."полная покоя,благостная"